# Userscript: changing AngularJS ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, userscripts

I'm writing a script to make my work easier. I've got an textarea, where i paste programmatically some data  (`el.value = ""`) and want to post/submit it but I'm unable to do so because `ng-pristine` and `ng-empty` is blocking my way. Is there any solution for this?

My code for "pasting" the data looks like this:

```
function transfer(){
        var fromV = document.getElementById('DataToCopy').value;
        var toV1 = document.getElementById('TextareaToPasteTo1');
        var toV2 = document.getElementById('TextareaToPasteTo2');
        var foc = document.querySelector('TextareaToPasteTo');
        foc.focus();
        toV1.value += "transferring to: " + fromV;
        toV2.value += "transferring to: " + fromV;
};
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Create a demo to reproduce an issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the markAsDirty method, like this:

```
control.markAsDirty();
```

This will also mark all direct ancestors as dirty to maintain the model.

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#!#markAsDirty-anchor

Comment: Thanks but that won't do, I need a pure Javascript or JQuery solution for Userscript

Comment: Can I message you on Skype? I'm actually writing this script to improve performance of the HCL IT analyst team

Answer (score 0):

why don't you clear all your classes *unless it affects your UI*, in your `transfer` method?

```
document.getElementsByName('whatever')[0].classList = [];
```

this will remove all `ng-valid, ng-invalid, ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched, ng-empty, ng-not-empty` classes if any, along with other classes.

*if in case it affects your UI, you can add the needed classes manually*

```
document.getElementsByName('whatever')[0].classList = ['some-class', 'some-other-class'];
```

Comment: Damn, I thought of doing it that way but didn't think that it might actually work. Guess what happened, I'm an idiot and it worked perfectly... After my 2 days struggle to find the solution, many thanks!

Comment: @CardboardHammer Glad! accept it as your answer then :)

Comment: well, I tested it when I had more time and it occured that the value "pasted" into the textarea was not displaying after submition (weird I haven't noticed that after the first time). I'm thinking that what happened was that the ng-models were changed client side and not "forwarded" to the server. I managed to fix it though, posted the fix as resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to find a solution. Using `.classList = [];` is changing the class on the client side but I needed to push the information that there is actually some text in the textarea to the server, so I fired an event and it worked!
`angular.element(jQuery('#activity-stream-textarea')).triggerHandler('input')`.